# Local static variable initialization - bug of Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, initialization, static-variables

I recently debugged some legacy code like this:

```
template<size_t count>
struct SomeData
{
    char m_data[count];
};

template<>
struct SomeData<0>
{
};

template<int n>
struct SomeDataLength : public SomeDataLength<n-1>
{
    SomeDataLength(){ value[n] = sizeof(SomeData<n>); }
};

template<>
struct SomeDataLength<0>
{
    SomeDataLength(){ value[0] = sizeof(SomeData<0>); }

    size_t value[10];
};

template<typename T>
void SomeClass::SomeMethod(size_t count)
{
    ...

    static SomeDataLength<5> dataLength;

    size_t length = dataLength.value[count]; // sometimes may be 0 on the method first call

    ...
}
```

It was surprising for me to discover that `length` variable can equal to `0` sometimes (rather rarely) on the `SomeMethod` first call.
Doesn't the C++ Standard gives a guarantee that local static variables must be initialized before accessing or this is a bug of compiler?

P.S. `value` array is never modified outside of SomeDataLength constructor. The compiler is the one from Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: sftrabbit, fixed. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: it happens only when count <= 5 ? if count > 5 it's quite logical that value is 0 since only the first five cells of value are initialized with SomeDataLength<5> dataLength;

Comment: Servé Laurijssen, yes it happens when count = 4. And as I already said it happens with rather low probability only on the first call of the method after application start. Subsequent calls are always fine.

Comment: Your code couldn't be compiled by gcc until I add `SomeDataLength<n-1>::` before `value` in c-tor. e.g.: `SomeDataLength(){ SomeDataLength<n-1>::value[n] = sizeof(SomeData<n>); }`. Maybe MSVC thinks that it's some *other* `value` ?? Try to change the code as above

Comment: Sounds like [this bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/746973/incorrect-c-11-value-initialization-for-type-with-implicitly-declared-but-non-trivial-default-constructor). Apparently, MSVC can fail to value-initialise members of base classes.

Comment: Are you using threading?  "C++ scoped static initialization is not thread-safe, on purpose!" http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/03/08/85901.aspx